# Is it sufficient to compare two measures on a generator?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two measures defined on a common sigma algebra $\Omega$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a non-trivial generator of $\Omega$.
If $\mu_1(A) \leq \mu_2(A)$ for every element $A \in \mathcal{G}$, is this sufficient to say that $\mu_1(B) \leq \mu_2(B)$ for every element $B\in\Omega$?

Comment: For generator you mean any collection of sets $\mathscr{A}$ that satisfies: $\sigma(\mathscr{A})=\Omega$? In that case no because you can take $\Omega=\{\emptyset,A,B,X\}$ where $A\cup B=X$ and $\mathscr{A}=\{A\}$ and $2$ probability measures to see it is not true.

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any set with at least one element and let the set of generators be empty, so that the condition is trivially satisfied. What does that tell you about the measure of $X$?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I have edited the question accordingly to require the existence of a generator.

Comment: The way you asked the question, $\mathcal{G}=\emptyset$ would be the generator.